# How can I convert my Java project to an jar file with all the external libraries which i have used in my project?

Tags: java

hi i have converted my java project into jar file by NetBeans  and give it to my friend .
Whenever he click on that jar he is getting exception and then i have tried from cmd to run it then it was showing error like iText.pdf.* missing .

It means in that jar file the external library which i have used in my project is not there .
so guys please give me a solution that how i convert my java project along with the external library i have used into a .exe file

Thanks in advance

Comment: right click on eclipse projects  and export as jar, there you could find options like want to make runnable and would you like to embade external jar within that jar or not .. blah blah ...

Comment: see maven assembly plugin with `jar-with-dependencies` option

Comment: hi Naveen Ramawat .. i am using NetBeans not eclipse

Comment: @GautamReloaded: maven can be used regardless of the IDE being Netbeans or Eclipse. However, I'd suggest using the maven shade plugin instead of the assembly plugin, since it is more versatile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ant, maven or gradle for this things. If you use Eclipse IDE it has own default ant so simply go with right click on project and export to JAR file.

Comment: hi ..can i open a netBeans project in Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

I believe this link should help you with this issue : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/single-jar-141905.html

This will package every dependent library (*.jar) into one single Project.jar.

Another solution is to use something such as Apache Maven with NetBeans :
http://wiki.netbeans.org/Maven

Answer (score 0):

What usually I do is, Just giving clean and build and in netbeans_project_directory/dist folder will be having all necessary things, such as executable jar and lib, you can create a bat file to execute the jar.

Comment: i have tried this as you are telling that clean and build ..but still getting same problem

Comment: You got class not found exception or anything else. Can you tell me what is the exception you got?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/itextpdf/text/Element

Comment: Please open your jar file winzip/winrar and open META-INF\MANIFEST.MF in notepad and check you have Entries like "Class-Path: lib/itextpdf-x.x.x.jar"

Comment: hey pasupathi ..i have checked what you have told ..and yes there is entries like lib/itextpdf....
so what to do now ..please suggest me

Comment: How you're executing this application? Did you converted the application into exe? Have you try to use java -jar command to execute the application?

Comment: yep .. i am using only jar file here ..no exe file

Comment: No clue man. lib\itextpdf-x.x.x.jar should be present in lib directory. And the MANIFEST.MF should have entry for this jar. That's it, you can run the application by java -jar app.jar Still you're facing issue means something else. You try to validate the itextpdf-x.x.x.jar whether it is able to open with winzip/winrar. The jar might be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

In your project properties, add "copy depedent librairies"(under "Build"->"Packaging"):

-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/REP9o.png

Then, when you build your project, Netbeans will include the lib in a folder called "lib".